# fineuploader with an existing form

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to use fineuploader as part of a product returns form. The user should be able to upload several images along with some form fields for the user to enter the reason for the return etc.

As such I want to be able to do two things:

1. Submit the form once with all files attached
2. Perform some non html5 JavaScript field validation before allowing the form to submit

Is this possible with Fineuploader and if not are there any workarounds?